# CSS not saving when using PostCSS in Gatsby.js development mode

Tags: css, caching, gatsby, postcss, css-modules

When using PostCSS with CSS modules in Gatsby.js, when I fire up development mode, the CSS files are not applied. To resolve it, I have to open each CSS file and save it for it to be applied.

I'm using the `gatsby-plugin-postcss` plugin. We use CSS module like `style.module.css`. Everything works when each CSS file is manually saved or when in build mode.

How can I resolve the CSS bug on gatsby.js?

Comment: Could you please share which options worked for you? ✌️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's a bug, it possibly a default configuration. According to the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-postcss/#postcss-plugins):

> If you need to override the default options passed into [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/tree/version-1)
>
> Note: Gatsby is using `css-loader@1.0.1`

```
// in gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    options: {
      cssLoaderOptions: {
        // your options here
      },
    },
  },     
],
```

Take a look at available options for the `1.0.1` versions to check if some of them fit your requirements to make it work in development mode.